# How to resize the UITableView row height in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I have a requirement like saving the data in itemsArray in the following format like

```
iPhone
iPad
iPod Touch
```

and the same data I am tryin to display in the UITableView

but it is taking only the first item `i.e iPhone`

It is not displaying the remaining items in the itemsArray.

I have been trying this but I am not able to find the solution for it.

Can anyone please help me to solve this.

I am new to Objective C.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all 3 items in single cell then create one dictionary as follows:

```
NSMutableArray * contentsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary * allContacts = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(int i = 0; i < yourItemArrayCount; i++) {

    [allContacts setObject:[yourItemArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"key %@",[[youtItemArray objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]];

}
[contentsArray addObject:allContacts];
```

then in following method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        //Write your dictionary logic here

      NSDictionary *dict = [contentsArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
      //Necessary logic will go here.
}
```

Add following method in your code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60; //You can set height of cell here.
}
```

Comment: it is the right answer is related to the ?, your answer is related to static data not the dynamic data. please modify the answer

Comment: It must be added to the delegate object of the UITableView object.

Comment: @NicolasBuquetShe already set the delegates because she got value in tableview but not in proper format.

Comment: @iPhone I want dynamically.In that array I am getting three item.In some times i wlil get more than that like 7 r 8 items at that time how can I achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Debug your datasource in table datasource/delegates. Your problem is only for 3 items. It can be done statically as given in above blog.

But for actually resizing table view cell/row height. you will have to use autolayouts.

Follow the link: 
//http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: Ya I am using autolayout.

Comment: I need to see your code in order to check the issue.  Because if you are using autolayout and your labels are not getting the data then autolayout will shrink the height of the tablecell. These could be the possibilities rest you show me your code.

Comment: check the following cases in your code: 1) height of the cell in XIB and in the datasource method (heightForRowAtindexPath). 2) debug in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource that labels are receiving the data.